Audio sent with the MIME type audio/mpeg, but processed as octect - API WhatsApp
I'm capturing audio via the web using the JavaScript MediaRecorder API. I then send this media to a Go server, which then sends it to WhatsApp.
Form in Go:
vFile,_= os.Open(this.URL)

vBuffer := new(bytes.Buffer)

vMultipart := multipart.NewWriter(vBuffer)

vMIMEHeader := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)

vMIMEHeader.Set("Content-Disposition","form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + this.GetFileName() + "\"")
vMIMEHeader.Set("Content-Type",vMIMEType)

vIOWriter, _ := vMultipart.CreatePart(vMIMEHeader)

io.Copy(vIOWriter,vFile)

vIOWriter, _ = vMultipart.CreateFormField("type")
vIOWriter.Write([]byte(vMIMEType))

vIOWriter, _ = vMultipart.CreateFormField("messaging_product")
vIOWriter.Write([]byte("whatsapp"))

vMultipart.Close()


this.GetFileName() = "audio.mp3"
vMIMEType = "audio/mpeg"

When uploading the file, WhatsApp successfully receives it and creates an id for it.
However, when sending an audio message referencing the created id, I receive the following return:
"errors":[{"code":131053,"title":"Media upload error","message":"Media upload error","error_data":{"details":"Audio file uploaded with mimetype as audio/mpeg, however on processing it is of type application/octet-stream. Please choose a different file."}}]
Thanks for all the help.
Some points:
A) I searched the documentation and the media type is allowed;
B) I sent the file in mp3 format stating the MIME type as audio/mpeg;
Documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/error-codes
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#supported-media-types
Information added after posting:
A) I'm encoding the bytes of the mp3 file in base64 for storage and then I read it and decode it to send to WhatsApp. With images and videos it's working fine. I'm using the methods base64.StdEncoding.EncodeString and base64. StdEncoding.DecodeString to do so.
B) When creating the file for Upload to WhatsApp, I can listen to the recorded audio normally.
C) The audio propagation flow is as follows:
Web page -> GO Server -> Base64 Encoding -> Save in CLOB column in the Oracle database -> Read the column and decode to bytes -> Create the file with these bytes in a folder -> Send the file to WhatsApp through the code mentioned in the publication -> Send the message referencing the returned media id -> Obtaining the error described in the publication.

«…however on processing it is of type…»–I, for one, read it as the server has actually attempted to parse the file and it appears the contents of the file is not MP3. Maybe it's something other–like base64-encoded MP3? A ZIP file with MP3? I personally find the statement vFile,_= os.Open(this.URL) to look very strange, so I have no idea what may be happening here.

I'm encoding the bytes of the mp3 file in base64 for storage and then I read it and decode it to send to WhatsApp. With images and videos it's working fine. I'm using the methods base64.StdEncoding.EncodeString and base64. StdEncoding.DecodeString to do so.

Can you verify the file is indeed MP3 by running some independent tool on it after decoding from base64? I mean, running file that/file.mp3 and/or ffprobe -i that/file.mp3 would do (the latter is a part of the ffmpeg package).

Input: ffprobe -i 1279.mp3
Output:
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '1279.mp3':
Metadata:
encoder         : Chrome
Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
--
(Info) Código de criação do arquivo:
vFile,_ := os.Create("C:/Chat/Midia/1279.mp3")
vBytesArqMidia,_ = base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(vMidiaBase64)
vFile.Write(vBytesArqMidia)
vFile.Close()

kostix, what you reported was actually the problem. According to the test I posted with the library you passed, for some reason, the file had content in the "webm" format. I used the same library and converted the file generated by Go back to mp3. I used the following code: exec.Command("ffmpeg.exe", "-i", "1279.webm", "-vn", "-acodec", "libmp3lame", "1279.mp3").Run() . Thank you very much.,

The audio captured by MediaRecorder in all browsers save Safari uses the webm (Matroska) container format, and is likely encoded with Opus. No browser generates mp3.
